# SQL Selecting one record from two tables, then update it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database, Users and Staff. Self explanatory I hope.  Attributes common to both tables are:

---

### | id | Reference | First_Name | Last_Name | Email |...

In my user.php file, there's a lot of functions used to update an attribute for a user's account. Currently it's very inefficient because I have had to split the queries to check if a user is in the Users table or the Staff table, then do the same thing in order to push any changes back to my database.

I'd like a single query to do the hard work of finding the record from two tables.

```
    //Check the USERS table first
    $LocateAccount__UsersTable_Query = $CTDatabase->prepare("SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE Reference='$Account_Reference'");
    $LocateAccount__UsersTable_Query-> execute();
    $LocateAccount__UsersTable_Count = $LocateAccount__UsersTable_Query->rowCount();

if ($LocateAccount__UsersTable_Count > 0){
    //Fetch the user's record
    // echo "USER IS USER";
      $Located_Account = $LocateAccount__UsersTable_Query->fetch(); 


  } else {
    //Account not found in USERS table, so check STAFF table
    $LocateAccount__StaffTable_Query = $CTDatabase->prepare("SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE Reference='$Account_Reference'");
    $LocateAccount__StaffTable_Query-> execute();
    $LocateAccount__StaffTable_Count = $LocateAccount__StaffTable_Query->rowCount();

    if ($LocateAccount__StaffTable_Count > 0){
      //Account has been found in the USERS table
      $Located_Account = $LocateAccount__StaffTable_Query->fetch(); 
      //Fetch the STAFF user's record
      // echo "USER IS STAFF";

    } else {
      echo 'An error message goes here..';
    }
```

**Question 1:** How can I find a user in either Users or Staff tables in one single query?

**Question 2:** How can I then UPDATE an attribute on a single entry in one of these tables in a single query?

Things I am looking into, using EXISTS, but I get errors when trying the code in Sequel Pro:
[SQL Data from One of Two Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386768/sql-data-from-one-of-two-tables)

Comment: Change the data structure to a single user table with a column indicating `user` or `staff`

Comment: Isn't there a way I can do this without? That's what I am looking for.

Comment: Probably, but it would be better to fix the orignal error than code around it

Comment: Curious to know why it's a problem with separating the data? I thought it would be more efficient as the staff table won't be getting half as much use as the users table

Comment: This is failing you `("SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE Reference='$Account_Reference';` for 2 reasons, IF that's your real code. Same thing for `("SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE Reference='$Account_Reference';
    $LocateAccount__StaffTable_Query-> execute();`

Comment: Ah yes there was a typo. I was having issues formatting it when pasting it in place. Should be correct now.

Comment: both your endings `');` are missing a double quote `'");`

Comment: @Fred-ii- In the grand scheme of things, it doesn't really matter. You still get the idea of what it was I was doing, I don't want to use my current method anyway. So if you can provide a solution to my issue then great, if not then take care.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 'Reference' column will have unique values across both the tables, you can use `UNION` operator to search both the tables with same value, e.g.:

```
select Reference, first_name, last_name from users where Reference = ?
UNION
select Reference, first_name, last_name from staff where Reference = ?
```

You can also update both the tables in one query using `join`, e.g.:

```
UPDATE users,staff SET table1.col=a,table2.col2=b
WHERE users.reference = ?;
```

Comment: Thank you this works! However, I have to reference 24 individual columns manually which is quite a pain as SELECT * doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with IF EXISTS(in users table) ELSE IF EXISTS (in staff table)